# Nodejs web applications framework with hmvc

Tags: node.js, express, hmvc

I am doing some web apps development and i would like to have a hmvc structure to enable my app have php lke modules in frameworks like kohana and other php frameworks.Is there a framework i can use for this or way i can modify express to handle hmvc modules?.

Answer (score 0):

Express is actually open source, and the main thing it has is middlewares(by which you add things like static files, session support and so on) and request, response objects, sources of express are so easy to understand. Question is actually is prototype oriented nature of javascript can make implementation of HMVC elegant and easy to write, I think it is possible, because it is not so verbose. Probably you even don't need to modify sources, because some things is possible to embed as middleware and using app.use function, even if you need to do it extremely easy to understand. The one problem is not in express. It is in node asynchronous nature, you can't write code using blocks. If you think it is possible to write it using async code you can reach success in it.